# Jquery clone of html

Tags: jquery, html, clone

Trying to learn and understand cloning html.  So I have some HTML where I am getting holidays from a json test feed that i created....basic...has a date and holiday name.

```
<table id="holidayTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="holidayDateHead">Holiday Date</th>
            <th class="holidayNameHead">Holiday Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <tr id="emptyRow" class="tableRow">
        <td class="holidayDate"></td>
        <td class="holidayName"></td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am doing an ajax to get the json and using this to go through it.

```
var holidayCount = 0;  //Count of Items.
        $(HolidayData).each(function(index, Holidays) {

            var date = Holidays.holidayDate.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(.*)/g, '$2/$3/$1');
            var templateClone = $("#emptyRow .tableRow").clone()[0];

            $(".holidayDate", templateClone).text(date);
            $(".holidayName", templateClone).text(Holidays.name);

            $("#holidayTable").append(templateClone);

            holidayCount++;
        });
```

However this doesnt seem to work right and not sure why.....I can console.log the count and i get 10....which are the number f holidays i put in the json....however it only shows 1 in the web page.  I dont see any errors in the console....so nothing is giving me an idea about why its not working.

Can anyone shed some light on this to help me understand this a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your example and could make work:

On clicking on button with id="clone" the empty row is cloned, filled with data and appended as a new row to the table:

```
$('#clone').on('click',function() {

 var templateClone = $("#emptyRow").clone();

   $(".holidayDate", templateClone).text('24.12.2015');
   $(".holidayName", templateClone).text('Christmas');

   templateClone.appendTo("#holidayTable tbody");
});
```

I you want to try for yourself go to this plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/8EmVxUkg2VNOYvLqTPZl/

Comment: This is great....this works.....but was wondering.....there is an empty row when I look at it in chrome....should that be hidden once data populates the template?

I am going to look at this more closely to get a better understanding of how this is done.

Comment: Ok...I got everything to work....I ended up removing the first tr using jquery as I could see that in chrome and it had a small space between the names and the data.  I also used jquery to remove all of the same ids (#emptyRow) as well.  Still playing and experimenting with this.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var templateClone = $("#emptyRow .tableRow").clone()[0];
```

to

```
var templateClone = $("#emptyRow .tableRow").first().clone();
```

Reason: using [0] does return a HTML-DOM-element and not a jquery-object.